# Is there a way to output the definition of a function in PHP?

Tags: php

```
function func() {
    // ...
}
```

I have the function name `"func"`, but not its definition.

In JavaScript, I'd just use `alert()` to see the definition.

Is there a similar function in PHP?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the methods getFileName(), getStartLine(), getEndLine() defined in [ReflectionFunctionAbstract](http://docs.php.net/class.reflectionfunctionabstract) to read the source code of functions/methods from their source file (if there is any).

e.g. (without error handling)

```
<?php
printFunction(array('Foo','bar'));
printFunction('bar');


class Foo {
  public function bar() {
    echo '...';
  }
}

function bar($x, $y, $z) {
  //
  //
  //
  echo 'hallo';

  //
  //
  //
}
//


function printFunction($func) {
  if ( is_array($func) ) {
    $rf = is_object($func[0]) ? new ReflectionObject($func[0]) : new ReflectionClass($func[0]);
    $rf = $rf->getMethod($func[1]);
  }
  else {
    $rf = new ReflectionFunction($func);
  }
  printf("%s %d-%d\n", $rf->getFileName(), $rf->getStartLine(), $rf->getEndLine());
  $c = file($rf->getFileName());
  for ($i=$rf->getStartLine(); $i<=$rf->getEndLine(); $i++) {
    printf('%04d %s', $i, $c[$i-1]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>I don't know of one.</s>See code at bottom.  There is a [function to list all the defined functions](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-functions.php).  There's another to [get the values of all the arguments to the current function](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php), and the [number of arguments](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php).  And there's one to [see if a function exists](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php).  But there doesn't seem to be one to name the current function, nor any means of listing formal parameters.

Even when a runtime error occurs, it doesn't list a call stack, nor state the function that's active:

```
PHP Warning:  Division by zero in t.php on line 6
```

Edit:  For the code to identify where it is, add this:

```
echo "At line " .__LINE__ ." of file " . __FILE__ ."\n";
```

It gives the output

```
At line 7 of file /home/wally/t.php
```

Edit 2:  I found this function in my code which looks to be what you want:

```
function traceback ($showvars)
{
        $s = "";
        foreach (debug_backtrace($showvars) as $row)
        {
                $s .= "$row[file]#$row[line]: ";
                if(isset($row['class']))
                        $s .= "$row[class]$row[type]$row[function]";
                else    $s .= "$row[function]";
                if (isset($row['args']))
                        $s .= "('" . join("', '",$row['args']) . "')";
                $s .= "<br>\n";
        }
        return $s;
}
```

For example, it produces:

```
[wally@zf ~]$ php -f t.php
/home/wally/t.php#24: traceback('1')<br>
/home/wally/t.php#29: t('1', '2', '3')<br>
/home/wally/t.php#30: x('2', '1')<br>
/home/wally/t.php#31: y('2', '1')<br>
/home/wally/t.php#33: z('1', '2')<br>
```

Comment: So in PHP it's impossible to do what I want?

Comment: Can't you just look at the source, given that you know the function name?

Comment: I'm reading drupal's code.It'll take quite some time to find the definition for the first time.

Comment: @wallyk,but the context is:I don't know where the code is,and I can't modify the source code.